# Is it likely that increased understanding of quantum physics will change our understanding of chemistry?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, atoms

Reading that the [large hadron collider will be up and running with twice as much energy](http://news.sciencemag.org/people-events/2014/12/areas-watch-2015) in March 2015, I was curious whether our understanding of subatomic particles has changed our understanding of chemistry.

Edit: To attempt to narrow down the question to something with a definitive answer: has the discovery of subatomic particles changed experimental chemistry?  If so, what is an example?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! This question of yours is mostly based on hypothetical predictions of the future; thus, in spite of the fact that these predictions are somehow "science-based", good answers could be too many. Chemistry.SE is based on conceptual chemistry, rather than chatty predictions. You might need to take a look at [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to find out which questions are not appreciable in our community, or be kind enough to take a [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.

Comment: In my opinion, nowadays' science, specially chemistry, is *not* something that can be blown away with a single wind, if that's what you meant. There couldn't be principal errors today since the science now is mostly experimental, not theoretical.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you asked for an example, I'll give you one.
"Quantum" is undeniably the most effective keyword our science has seen, it's changed our 'understanding of chemistry and physics' drastically over the past century. 
For example, between 1900 to 1925 (years vary from source to source, but this era exists, that's what that is important), in which Bohr's model was the main focus of study (as wikipedia puts it), is known to be the era of **"old quantum theory"**.
 There were series of theories, which started by Max Plank, and partially came to results with the final modifications of Sommerfeld; and ended in Erwin Schrodinger's famous model. New efforts led to new results and therefore the "old quantum theory" was never consistent.
What was all of this about? Scientists are always eager to find out the differential behavior of matter and energy. Sub-atomic particles (in first level, n, p & e) were discovered in order to explain the phenomenons that Roentgen saw (radioactivity of Uranium and other heavy elements in 'pitchblende'); Faraday experimented (the $\ce{SnCl2}$ solution experiment); Greek Leucippus and Democritos tried to explain; and so on. After every discovery, since the 'rules' that were discovered usually were up to a point in explaining what's around us, we change them and make new discoveries. And that was the reason of what Einstein, Bell and people like those did. They corrected the quantum for it to be what we know today.
So you see, the science was always about understanding; so why wouldn't a big discovery like quantization that led to quantum mechanics be able to change our direction of thought, either we are chemists, physicists or simply *humans*?
Links you might find helpful: [About the old quantum theory in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_quantum_theory); [About the old quantum theory 2](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.1366); [Bell's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem)(which linked classical quantum to quantum mechanics) and finally [quantum mechanics according to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics).

Answer (score 0):

I find this a strange question, because all contemporary chemical bond theory is quantum mechanical. So quantum mechanics already influences chemistry a great deal (look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chemistry))! I suppose you could ask whether deeper quantum theory gives us more knowledge, and I'd guess yes! For example, look at this Periodic Videos analysis of the chemistry of seaborgium ([link](http://www.periodicvideos.com/videos/seaborgium_compound.htm)). We need more experimental data to test all theories, including the quantum mechanical ones.